# Broadcast after url changing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, broadcast

I'd like to broadcast some data after a $window.location

So in my first js file where I execute the searchSelect function I have;

```
$scope.searchSelect = function (item) {        
    var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/import.aspx?key=IMPORT_" + item.type;
    $window.location.href = url;
    $scope.$broadcast('searched', {type: item.type})
}
```

And in a second js file i have :

```
$scope.$on('searched', function (event, args) {
    console.log(args.type);        
})
```

But the console.log won't appear.

How could I do this broadcast after the URL location change? Thanks

Comment: it change the url, it works, i'm on the new page but i can't catch the broadcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two changes:

1. use broadcast before changing URL.
2. use rootscope for broadcast.

i.e.
use this statement:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('searched', {type: item.type})
```

before this

```
$window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: doesn't work for me :/ i put 'debugger;' in the $scope.$on... but nothing happens

Comment: I think there can be problem with controller inheritance. You can try using `$rootScope.$on` to listen for the broadcast event.